# how to convert .txt files to ReST in linux

Tags: linux, restructuredtext

In Documentation of linux kernel tree I need to convert .txt files to ReST. Is it like simply renaming the extension like .rst?

Comment: See Sphinx documentation on [`source_suffix`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-source_suffix).

Answer (score 1):

Having had a cursory glance over a few files in the `documentation` directory of the kernel source tree I'd say nothing needs doing, they seem to be in `rst` markup; the extensions don't matter in Linux.